# Error: Current componentRef is different for cached componentRef

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

I'm developing a NativeScript Angular 2 application.

I have a ListView that contains a bunch of objects. Tapping one of these objects opens up a new Component. After I press the back button to go back to the list and press on another object in the list, I get the following error:

How can I fix this?

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/./bundles/core.umd.js:1091:24: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Current componentRef is different for cached componentRef
    deactivate@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/router/page-router-outlet.js:105:32 [angular]
    deactiveRouteAndOutlet@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4578:30 [angular]
    deactiveRouteAndItsChildren@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4538:40 [angular]
    deactivateRoutes@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4467:49 [angular]
    file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4429:35 [angular]
    forEach@[native code] [angular]
    deactivateChildRoutes@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4428:36 [angular]
    activate@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4415:35 [angular]
    file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/./bundles/router.umd.js:4034:30 [angular]
    file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:110:25 [angular]
    __tryOrSetError@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:247:20 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:187:42 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:125:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:143:34 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23:31 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js:49:28 [angular]
    _trySubscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:35 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:40 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    _innerSub@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:130:55 [angular]
    _tryNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:127:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:110:26 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:143:34 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23:31 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/reduce.js:119:34 [angular]
    complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:114:27 [angular]
    _complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:135:38 [angular]
    complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:114:27 [angular]
    _subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js:116:32 [angular]
    _trySubscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:35 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:40 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    _innerSub@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:130:55 [angular]
    _tryNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:127:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:110:26 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:143:34 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23:31 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:143:34 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23:31 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyComplete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/every.js:53:30 [angular]
    _complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/every.js:70:28 [angular]
    complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:114:27 [angular]
    _complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:135:38 [angular]
    complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:114:27 [angular]
    _subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js:116:32 [angular]
    _trySubscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:35 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:40 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    _innerSub@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:130:55 [angular]
    _tryNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:127:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:110:26 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyComplete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/every.js:53:30 [angular]
    _complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/every.js:70:28 [angular]
    complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:114:27 [angular]
    _complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:135:38 [angular]
    complete@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:114:27 [angular]
    _subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js:116:32 [angular]
    _trySubscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:35 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:40 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    _innerSub@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:130:55 [angular]
    _tryNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:127:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:110:26 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:143:34 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23:31 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js:49:28 [angular]
    _trySubscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:57:35 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:45:40 [angular]
    subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:26 [angular]
    _innerSub@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:130:55 [angular]
    _tryNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:127:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:110:26 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    notifyNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js:143:34 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js:23:31 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/map.js:83:30 [angular]
    next@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:23 [angular]
    _subscribe@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js:49:28 [angular]
```

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error because the details page was referencing a object property in the actionbar... (looks like it was not instantiated at the time the action bar got rendered) Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah I got this same error because an object in the component was undefined and was being referenced in the view.  It produced an object undefined error on the first tap and then the above error on subsequent taps

Answer (score 0):

I just added an *ngIf in my attribute to verify that it's not undefined.

Example:

```
<StackLayout *ngIf="example">
    <Label textWrap="true" [text]="example.title"></Label>
    <Image [src]="example.image" height="100"></Image>
</StackLayout>
```